# Programmatically created nodes are shown only after re-saving

Tags: views, datetime

I'm creating a lot of nodes programmatically in a custom module. These nodes are showing up on admin/content and in a default view display (unformatted/fields), but not in a calendar view display. Only if I open and resave, those nodes will be shown in the calendar view.

Why is this happening? All nodes are published.

Comment: Does anything change in the node's devel page after re-saving?

Comment: Thanks for poining me that direction, Niall. You're right, the "path" array (one value in there: "1") is missing in my created nodes. This could be coming from pathauto, can this be the reason for my nodes to not show up?

Comment: The missing path was not the problem.. I've added "$node->path['pathauto'] = TRUE;" before node->save($node). Now the path alias is present, but the nodes are still missing in the calendar.

Comment: SOLVED: I was using a timestamp for the generated dates, it needed to be a string like: "1967-01-15T00:00:00". I needed to look up the values in my database directly, devel / dpm() did not show a difference.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was using a timestamp for the generated dates, but it needed to be a string like: "1967-01-15T00:00:00". I needed to look up the values in my database directly, devel / dpm() did not show a difference.